# Possible improvements to window swallowing program?

Tags: beginner, rust, linux, x11

I have written a small program that swallows windows. It works in X.org using the xcb library. This is my first rust program but I have lots of other programming experience.

Any general improvements are great, but a specific problem I've been having is that if the program exits too quickly (child process is short) there's a chance the parent window isn't remapped. I have gotten around this by using the `sleep` function, but this is only a quick fix and slows the program down noticeably.

I have tried many different features of xcb like `set_input_focus`, `change_window_attribute` and `wait_for_event` among others. I have also tried different logical solutions like running `map_window` multiple times or running the command through `sh -c`.

Here is the source code:

```
extern crate xcb;
use std::{env, process, thread, time};

fn main() {
    let (conn, _screen_num) = xcb::Connection::connect(None).unwrap();
    let win = xcb::get_input_focus(&conn).get_reply().unwrap().focus();
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    let mut command = process::Command::new(&args[1]);
    command.args(&args[2 .. args.len()]);

    xcb::unmap_window(&conn, win);
    conn.flush();
    let stat: i32 = command.status().unwrap().code().unwrap();
    xcb::map_window(&conn, win);
    conn.flush();

    thread::sleep(time::Duration::from_millis(10));

    process::exit(stat);
}
```

And the GitHub link: https://github.com/EmperorPenguin18/gobble

Comment: Would `xcb::map_window_checked(&conn, win).request_check().unwrap()` help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @L. F. and @Cryptjar for their answers. It seems a combination of both fixed the problem for me. Using `xcb::map_window_checked(&conn, win).request_check()?` causes an error to be output instead of the program just crashing. For reference, make sure to use the anyhow crate like this: `fn main() -> Result<(), anyhow::Error> {`

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to Rust, and welcome to Code Review!

I do not have a Linux device at hand, so I will focus more on the code itself rather than the functionality.

## `extern crate`

In general, `extern crate` is [not needed since the 2018 edition](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64623808), barring some exceptional edge cases.  Since the examples on GitHub contain this directive, and I can't test the code, I assume `extern crate` is necessary here, but keep in mind that it isn't needed for the majority of crates.

## Formatting

Your code is compliant with the Official [Rust Style Guide](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/tree/master/style-guide) for the most part — the only difference is shown here:

```text
     let win = xcb::get_input_focus(&conn).get_reply().unwrap().focus();
     let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
     let mut command = process::Command::new(&args[1]);
-    command.args(&args[2 .. args.len()]);
+    command.args(&args[2..args.len()]);

     xcb::unmap_window(&conn, win);
     conn.flush();
```

You can use `cargo fmt` to automatically format your code.

## Spawning the process

I feel that configuring and executing the command all at once is more readable:

```rust
let args = env::args().collect();
let stat: i32 = process::Command::new(&args[1])
    .args(&args[2..])
    .status()
    .unwrap()
    .code()
    .unwrap();
```

Note that `&args[2..]` is equivalent to `&args[2..args.len()]`.

## Error handling

I recommend using the [`?` operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html#a-shortcut-for-propagating-errors-the--operator) and returning a `Result` instead of `unwrap`ping all the time.  The [`anyhow`](https://docs.rs/anyhow/1.0.41/anyhow/) crate comes in handy.